# downgrade mockery from laravel

Tags: laravel, centos, mockery, downgrade

I have laravel 7.20.0 which require php > 7.2.5. I have CentOS8 with php 7.2.24.

My problem is that when i run:

```
composer install
```

i receive followed problem:

```
- mockery/mockery 1.4.1 requires php ^7.3 || ^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.2.24) does not satisfy that requirement.
- Installation request for mockery/mockery 1.4.1 -> satisfiable by mockery/mockery[1.4.1].
```

Is it possible just to downgrade mockery?

Thanks in advance

Comment: According the the laravel [composer.json](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v7.20.0/composer.json) laravel itself requires mockery 1.3.1 so your requirement is probably coming from somewhere else.`composer show --tree` might show you where that requirement is coming from

Comment: You are right. I delete project and rebuild laravel. It work now. This mean requirement was comming from somewhere else. Thanks for advice.